# Desktop Duplication and C++ AMP incompatible?

Tags: windows, gpu, c++-amp, dxgi, desktop-duplication

I want to capture and compress the screen on the GPU.  C++ AMP and DXGI Desktop Duplication each work individually, but don't seem to work together.

**Example:**

[This project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a) works great, but adding minimal C++ AMP code near the top of DesktopDuplication.cpp makes it fail:

```
#include <amp.h>
//void f() { Concurrency::direct3d::create_accelerator_view( nullptr ); }
//void f() { Concurrency::accelerator default_acc; }
void f() { Concurrency::accelerator::get_all(); }
```

Even though `f()` is never called, `m_Factory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(...)` returns `E_ACCESSDENIED`. (The commented versions of `f()` produce the same result.)

In my own project, `IDXGIOutput1::DuplicateOutput()` returns `DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED` when I attempt to use C++ AMP.

What's going on?

---

Update: In the NVIDIA Control Panel, changing the "Preferred graphics processor" to "Integrated graphics" works. (But, using the NVIDIA card is *much* preferred.)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN does not state this as a mandatory requirement, however [still suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404611) that you don't use the API across mutlithreaded environment:

> An application can use `IDXGIOutputDuplication` on a separate thread to receive the desktop images and to feed them into their specific image-processing pipeline.

That is, it is suggested that you have a single loop aligned with specific thread that captures the updates, and further on you are free to leverage multithreading of sorts to speed up processing.